# Is there any way to initialize an array without brackets?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration

I have the question if there is any way to initialize an array with multiple elements without brackets, for example:

> `int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Since `*(a + 5)` equals with `a[5]` , why i cannot initialize  with:

> `int *(a + 5) = {1,2,3,4,5};`

*it gives me the error: expected ')' before '+' token*.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The `[]` in declaring an array and in indexing an array are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
int *(a + 5) = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

just is an invalid declaration because in the parentheses there is used the expression `( a + 5 )` with an entity named `a` that was not declared.

Without using square brackets you could write for example

```
typedef int T[5];

T a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

As for this your statement

> Since *(a + 5) equals with a[5] , why i cannot initialize with:

then in this context `*( a + 5 )` is not an array. It is an expression that yields an element `a[5]` provided that `a` was already declared as an array with the number of elements not less than `6`. Otherwise `a[5]` will be a non-existent element of the array `a`.

Comment: So i can't do this and the only way is by brackets only?

Comment: @AlexandrosGkainta In any case some way or another you need to use brackets to declare an array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Actually, if you really need to avoid brackets, there are ways to declare an array without them :)

Answer (score 5):

The equivalence of `E1[E2]` and `*(E1 + E2)` only applies to an **expression**.  What you have is a **declaration** which has different syntax rules.

So you need to use this syntax:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `a[5]` with `*(a + 5)` does not work in declarations or definitions.

If you really want to avoid square brackets (to win a bet I assume), here are 2 contorted but standard complying solutions:

Using trigraphs: `int a??(5??) = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Using digraphs: `int a<:5:> = {1,2,3,4,5};`

More information can be found in [Digraphs and Trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).

You can even write a fragment that will compile on recent compilers where trigraphs are disabled and digraphs supported:

```
// trick: the comment spans to the next line if trigraphs are enabled
#define TRIGRAPHS_DISABLED  1 //??/
-1

#if TRIGRAPHS_DISABLED
int a<:5:> = {1,2,3,4,5};
#else
int a??(5??) = {1,2,3,4,5};
#endif
```

Answer (score -3):

You may try like this:

```
int *arr=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&(*(arr+i)));
}    
or
int *arr=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
*(arr+0)=1;
*(arr+1)=2;
*(arr+2)=3;
*(arr+3)=4;
*(arr+4)=5;
```

Comment: No? `int *(iarr+10)={0};` is invalid C syntax. [See for yourself...](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ_fzsFuu) And I've never seen any declaration which looks like `Data_type *(identifier_size);`

Comment: It's a good idea to run the code you're going to post through a compiler before submitting your answer. Doing so will help you avoid posting invalid code such as this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. now i had made changes in that ,i tried in some different way please have a look

Comment: @AvinashJadhav this still does not answer the question. The question is about why an array can't be declared as `int *(a + 5) = {1,2,3,4,5};`.